# Symfony2 Doctrine ORM ManyToMany issue

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, fixtures

I have an M:M relation with 
User<->Role<->Group.
Now I have this following relation tables in my database (additionally to users, groups, roles):

role_group,
group_role,
role_user,
user_role

Is this right? I learned that i only need 2 relation tables for M:N.

The problem why I came to this is, that i get an Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException error, when I try to load the fixtures.

I assume its an mistake in the ORM ManyToMany Notation.

Here are the ORMs:
User Entity

```
namespace Chris\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="usermanagement_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Chris\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements  UserInterface,\Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     *
     */
    private $roles;

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->isActive = true;

    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRolesOld()
    {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }


    public function setRoles($roles){
        $this->roles[] = $roles;
    }

    public function removeRole(RoleInterface $role)
    {
        $this->roles->removeElement($role);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
     */
    private $vorname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60)
     */
    private $nachname;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getVorname()
    {
        return $this->vorname;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $vorname
     */
    public function setVorname($vorname)
    {
        $this->vorname = $vorname;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getNachname()
    {
        return $this->nachname;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $nachname
     */
    public function setNachname($nachname)
    {
        $this->nachname = $nachname;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLetzterLogin()
    {
        return $this->letzterLogin;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $letzterLogin
     */
    public function setLetzterLogin($letzterLogin)
    {
        $this->letzterLogin = $letzterLogin;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $isActive
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $letzterLogin;



    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;



    public function setId($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }


    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }


    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

Role Entity

```
namespace Chris\UserBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * Role
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Chris\UserBundle\Entity\RoleRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="usermanagement_roles")
 */

class Role implements RoleInterface {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $role;

    public function getRole() {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "User", inversedBy = "roles")
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection $users
     */
    protected $users;

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $users
     */
    public function setUsers($users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }


    public function setRoles($roles)
    {
        $this->role = $roles;

        // allows for chaining
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "Chris\UserBundle\Entity\Group", inversedBy = "groups")
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection $group
     */
    private $group;

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getGroup()
    {
        return $this->group;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $group
     */
    public function setGroup($group)
    {
        $this->group = $group;
    }

}
```

Group Entity

```
namespace Chris\UserBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * Group
 * @ORM\Table(name="usermanagement_groups")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Group {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->role = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", mappedBy="users")
     *
     */
    private $role;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=40, unique=true)
     */
    private $groupName;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $role
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        $this->role[] = $role;
    }


    public function getGroupName()
    {
        return $this->groupName;
    }

    public function setGroupName($group)
    {
        $this->groupName = $group;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "mappedBy" on one notation and "inversedBy" on the other.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
 *
 */
private $roles;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "User", mappedBy = "roles")
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection $users
 */
protected $users;
```

Other than that i think you have a mistake in your annotation in "Group" under the property "role" (it's mapped to users).

The mapping for roles is missing from the Groupt entity.

Comment: hey, i made the changes and the redundant tables are deleted. but i still got the Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException error when i load fixtures